# Retrieve Dashboard Running User in query

Tags: visualforce, html

I built this visualforce page and controller that does a query for records with the current user and then displays the results on a visualforce chart. We went to production and the users said no we don't necessarily care about the chart for ourselves we want to see other people's results.

I adjusted my controller to query for the RunningUserId of the Dashboard. This seems to work fine as it gets results. The problem is that when you change the viewing as it does not show the results for the new user it shows the same results. It's almost as if the RunningUserId is not being set each time the viewing as changes but is only changed and updated when you edit and save the Dashboard.

I inspected the element with Chrome and found where it is setting the viewing as user. Example:

[image: Dashboard HTML]

is there a way to traverse through the HTML to get to that id? Or is there a simpler way to get it?

Controller Example:

```
public with sharing class ISOGaugeControllerIndividualCurMo {
public Integer getMax2() {
    Decimal max1;
    Dashboard db = [select RunningUserId
                    FROM Dashboard
                    WHERE DeveloperName = 'ISO_Individual_Team_Dashboard'];

    List<AggregateResult> max =   [select sum(Goal__c) goal 
                            FROM ISO_Goal__c 
                            Where Goal__c != null 
                            AND (Goal_Date__c = THIS_MONTH OR Goal_Date__c = LAST_MONTH)
                            AND RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'
                            AND OwnerId = :db.RunningUserId];

    if(max[0].get('goal') == null){
        max1 = 0;
        }
    else {
         max1 = (Decimal)max[0].get('goal');      
         }
    Integer max2 = (Integer)max1.divide(1000, 0);
    return max2;
    }

public List<gaugeData> getData() {
    Dashboard db = [select RunningUserId
                    FROM Dashboard
                    WHERE DeveloperName = 'ISO_Individual_Team_Dashboard'];     

    List<gaugeData> data = new List<gaugeData>(); 
    List<AggregateResult> Actuals =   [select sum(amount__c) sum 
                                FROM Actuals__c 
                                Where Amount__c != null 
                                AND (Actual_Date__c = THIS_MONTH OR Actual_Date__c = LAST_MONTH)
                                AND ISO_Goal__r.RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'
                                AND ISO_Goal__r.OwnerId = :db.RunningUserId];

    if(actuals[0].get('sum') == null) {
        data.add(new gaugeData('Actual', 0));
        }     
        else {
             data.add(new gaugeData('Actual', (Integer)((Decimal)actuals[0].get('sum')).divide(1000, 0)));
             }
    return data;
}
// Wrapper class
public class gaugeData {

public String name { get; set; }
public Integer size { get; set; }

public gaugeData(String name, Integer data) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = data;
    }
}   
}
```

Visualforce page example:

```
<apex:page controller="ISOGaugeControllerIndividualCurMo">
<!-- Use the rendered="" attribute to conditionally show the error if your {!max2} variable is 0 --> 
<apex:outputText rendered="{!max2 == 0}"> 
                    <div style="color:blue;font-size: 40px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;padding-top: 60px">
                    No Records Available
                    </div>
</apex:outputText>
<!-- Now do the opposite side of this check within your chart's rendered="" attribute -->
<apex:chart height="180" width="400" animate="true" data="{!data}" legend="false" rendered="{!max2 != 0}">
    <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="top" title="(In Thousands $$$)" minimum="0" maximum="{!max2}" margin="-9"/>          
    <apex:gaugeSeries dataField="size" donut="50"/>
</apex:chart>
```

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to change the user ID in Javascript, Right ? I don't think that is good idea. Instead i would suggest use of salesforce analytics api.

Comment: well, I want to retrieve the user id of the viewing as user. By any means not necessarily Javascript. I'll check out the analytics api, maybe it's in there.